# How can I force all rational number output to be displayed as reals?

Tags: output-formatting

Mathematica is automatically changing the format of all numerical output evaluations to rationals; e.g.,

`FullSimplify[x * y/. x -> 1 /.y -> 1/2]`

yields 1/2 and not 0.5.

I have many such numerical functions to evaluate, and so I don't want to use on of those display functions each time. I want to make a change at the level of the notebook. Any suggestions?

#### Edit

I tried

`DecimalForm[x * y /. x -> 1 /. y -> 1/2]`

but the output is simply

> `DecimalForm[1/2]`.

Comment: try `FullSimplify[x*y /. x -> 1. /. y -> 1/2]` or `N@FullSimplify[x*y /. x -> 1 /. y -> 1/2]`?

Comment: That's helpful and works. But I want to change it at the level of Notebook. I don't want to do it for indvidual outputs

Comment: try `$Post = N;` (see [$Post](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html))

Comment: Why not specify your limits as reals? FullSimplify[x*y /. x -> 1.0 /. y -> 1/2] yields 0.5.